# Does Dependency Property implement Flyweight Pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, design-patterns

Is the dependency property system in WPF the Flyweight Pattern applied to save memory storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you could consider it as an implementation of the flyweight pattern yes.

Default values are shared across all controls of the same type. Only those properties that deviate from the default values take up extra memory.

Additional information can be found on [Christian Mosers blog](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html), or msdn's page on [value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

Comment: That link is rather irrelevant to the question, and why not link to the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) rather than some random blog?

Comment: @H.B.: [Christian Moser is an MVP](https://mvp.support.microsoft.com/profile/Moser), and that blog goes in great detail in explaining how DPs work. (Instead of just explaining how to use them as in the msdn documentation.)

Comment: So what? So does the official documentation, which is written by the people who actually are involved in the projects. Further i have seen a lot of bad code on that blog so my opinion of it is not the best.

Comment: @H.B.: I don't see how msdn goes into detail in the value resolution strategy, which is what was most relevant for the OP. The question wasn't 'what are dependency properties'.

Comment: MSDN is much more detailed, that was the main site, there is one just for [value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx). (Yet another thing in which the blog is off if you compare the hierarchies)

Answer (score -1):

You should not have to care about such implementation details, and to find out whether the system actually conforms to the pattern one would either need to get that imformation from the engineers involved or work through a mountain of decompiled code.

The only thing that matters is that dependency properties do not require any space unless set in one way or another.

Comment: I disagree - it is important to understand the concepts and design patterns applied **and** what the result of those concepts is - in this case that they do not consume any space by default. Implementations change, concepts stay largely the same.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: That is exactly my point, the implementation could change so if they now use pattern X that could change to pattern Y, the only thing that stays is that no space is comsumed by the properties itself, so why should one care about this? Of course the pattern itself may be of interest but that is completely independent of any system where it is used.